# Haskell mongodb: object id as string

Tags: mongodb, haskell

What is the correct way of retrieving object id as string? I am getting type errors and cant figure out how to cast it. Calling 'show' on it does not work.

Also, the other way round, if i have object id as string received from URL, for instance,how do I write it back to mongo. I don't understand how to convert it correctly.

Comment: Any sample code will be helpful

Comment: @Ankur Something simple like this: Database.MongoDB.at "_id" document

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using [mongoDB](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mongoDB) driver. `ObjectId` has `Show` and `Read` instances. Example:

```
import Database.MongoDB
import Text.Read

main :: IO ()
main = do
  oid <- genObjectId
  putStrLn $ show oid
  print (readEither (show oid) :: Either String ObjectId)
```

Output:

```
51d16cec08d0cf312a000000
Right 51d16cec08d0cf312a000000
```

Comment: Thank you. I realize it suppose to work with 'show'. If I try to use 'at' or 'lookup' on a document I get "*** Exception: user error (expected Integer: 51d051d830983b0cd7000000)" If I call show on it i get "No instance for (Val v0) arising from a use of `at'"

Comment: @r.sendecky this works for me: `look "_id" ["_id" := ObjId (read "51d1789508d0cf32b5000001")]`, so I don't see your issue